# Sending a code block to a find_all dynamic method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I am working with some complex queries using the dynamic find_all method and reached to a point where sending a block to that find_all method would really simplify my code.

Is there any plugin or work in-progress dealing with this?

In simple terms, I'd like to do something like:

```
@products = Product.find_all_by_ids(ids, .....) do |p|
            # do something to each product like      
            p.stock += 10
          end
```

Any other guide or better way of doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 2.3 introduced the `find_in_batches` and `find_each` methods (see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods.html#M001846)) for batch processing of many records.

You can thus do stuff like:

```
  Person.find_each(:conditions => "age > 21") do |person|
    person.party_all_night!
  end
```

Comment: Nice find, I had read about this before but didn't recall it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use the `.each` method which Enumerable provides like

```
@products = Product.find_all_by_ids(ids, .....)
@products.each { |p| p.stock += 10 }
```

There are even some [extensions to Enumerable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html) that Rails provides that might help you a bit if you're doing some common stuff.

Also, don't forget to save your objects with something like `p.save` if you want the changes to actually persist.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the actual approach I was using. However, my concern was wondering if there was a way to send it a block to do that kind of calculations.

Using two statements seemed a bit forceful

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this:

```
@products = Product.find_all_by_ids(ids).each do |p| 
  p.stock+=10
 end
```

In case you didn't know, each returns the array passed to it.